# Location query in Google maps in android

Tags: android, gps, location, maps

I have made an app utilizing Google Maps. I have added a marker of my current location in it. However, as soon as I open the app, I want it to zoom in to my location instead of showing the whole world at the `95302 23535919711008489` location first. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `animateCamera()` as below

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}
```

Please read the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views?hl=fr-FR#moving_the_camera)

Comment: Thanks,but actually i knew about it already.It is only the solution when i move.I am asking about the position of camera should be my location on opening.

Comment: Glad that it helped.. @AshishPrajapat

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>       LatLng cameraLatLng = new LatLng(savedLat, savedLng);
>                         googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment)   getSupportFragmentManager()
>                                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
>       googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
>                                 .newLatLngZoom(cameraLatLng, 7))
> ```

savedLat, savedLng your current location longitude and latitude.You can change zoom number ( 7 ) to your fitting.

Comment: where to write this ?